# Adding Points on a Graphic

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have three questions about the following code:

```
Plot[{1/2 - 3/2 \[Lambda], Min[1/2 - 3/2 \[Lambda], Sqrt[\[Lambda]]]}, {\[Lambda], 0, 1/9}, AxesLabel -> {\[Lambda], \[Gamma]}, PlotStyle -> Black, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, White}, 2 -> {Axis, Red}},  AxesStyle -> {Directive[Black], Directive[Blue]}, Epilog -> {Text[Style["FULLY ATTRACTIVE", 36], Scaled[{0.6, 0.25}]], Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

1. How can I plot a series of given points on the plot obtained by code shown? For example suppose I have the following series of points:

   ```
   {{0.000297159,0.029389}, {0.00114653,0.0566384}, {0.00249252,0.082004},{0.00428816,0.105703} (* etc. *)}
   ```
2. Is there a more effective way to write the text "FULLY ATTRACTIVE" in the red region of the plot?
3. How can I change the axes dimension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First thing let's plot the points

```
points = {{0.000297159, 0.029389}, {0.00114653, 
    0.0566384}, {0.00249252, 0.082004}, {0.00428816, 0.105703}(*etc.*)};
```

For that you can keep using `Epilog` while paying attention to make all its content a valid `Graphics` element:

```
plot = Plot[{1/2 - 3/2 \[Lambda], 
  Min[1/2 - 3/2 \[Lambda], Sqrt[\[Lambda]]]}, {\[Lambda], 0, 1/9}, 
 AxesLabel -> {\[Lambda], \[Gamma]}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, White}, 2 -> {Axis, Red}}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Directive[Black], Directive[Blue]}, 
 Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize[.02], Point[points]}]
```

The result is

[image: plot_with_points]

Your text can be fit into the red shape by making it a little smaller, but let's assume you don't want to manually find the good fit. A possibility is to use `WordCloud` to find a good layout for you (with the caveat that it's not preserving the ordering of the words, so this method is not valid in general for multi-words labels).

We need to define the appropriate mask:

```
mask = Binarize[
  Plot[{1/2 - 3/2 \[Lambda], 
    Min[1/2 - 3/2 \[Lambda], Sqrt[\[Lambda]]]}, {\[Lambda], 0, 1/9}, 
   AxesLabel -> {\[Lambda], \[Gamma]}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   TicksStyle -> Transparent, AxesStyle -> Black, 
   Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, White}}, Background -> Black]]
```

[image: text_mask]

Now we can compute the layout (`Erosion` is used to leave a little margin)

```
text = WordCloud["FULLY ATTRACTIVE", Erosion[mask, 5], 
  ColorFunction -> Black];
```

and use `Overlay` to compose it with the original plot without worrying too much about the coordinates

```
Overlay[{plot, text}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Batracos!

Comment: +1. Nice application of `WordCloud`!